# Animated background scroll between the ends of the image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have spent half an hour trying to find a suitable background animation effect for a panoramic view over a very wide image.

My current HTML and CSS structure/properties:

```css
/* Background image */
#bgImage {
 position: absolute;
 background-image: url('img/image.php?id=331266');
 background-position: center;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Panoramic image, 6480 x 1080 px -->
<div id="bgImage></div>

<div id="contentWrap">
  <div class="container>
    <div class="row>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h1>Trying to get this to work</h1>
        <p>...and look cool!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything is up for a change at this point, but I would like to keep it simple. As said, I've already tried looking for solutions, but managed to find nothing of what I'm looking for. I don't necessarily need the background to interact with mouse movement on the screen, so the background could just **scroll to the right, where the image ends, and then start turning back left - repeat.**

Any ideas on how to accomplish such an animation? I'm sure it's quite simple, but my head is not providing me with enough intel on how-to.

Comment: use the scroll position to move the background as required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what it is you're trying to do; you can just use CSS `@keyframes` to animate the background position back and forth.

```css
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
#bgImage{
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/524/500/250);
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<div id="bgImage"></div>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, and apparently the solution was a lot simpler than I thought! Any idea how to adjust the scrolling speed of it though? To make it less disturbing, it'd be nice to have it scroll a lot slower. :)

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Just change the time in `animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite alternate;` to something higher. @ProDexorite

Comment: Uff, just realized it after I posted my stupid question - dang it. Changed it to 60s which to my image and purpose seems pretty close to perfection. Many thanks, again - saved my day. :)